# disable 169.254.x.x routes for veth interfaces - pi4 buster

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi, network-interface, dhcpcd

I'm trying to disable 169.254.xx routes from being added to the route table on a pi4 (Raspbian 10 Buster). All I have read so far points to dhcp configuring link local address, APIPA, zeroconf.

Added noipv4ll and set eth0 to static ip in dhcpcd.conf with no joy.

[image]

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/dhcp $ cat /etc/dhcpcd.conf 
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
# Some non-RFC compliant DHCP servers do not reply with this set.
# In this case, comment out duid and enable clientid above.
#duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Respect the network MTU. This is applied to DHCP routes.
option interface_mtu

# Most distributions have NTP support.
#option ntp_servers

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate SLAAC address using the Hardware Address of the interface
#slaac hwaddr
# OR generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses based from the DUID
slaac private

# Example static IP configuration:
interface eth0
static ip_address=10.10.20.3/24
#static ip6_address=fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::ff/64
static routers=10.10.20.10
static domain_name_servers=10.10.20.3 1.1.1.1 

# It is possible to fall back to a static IP if DHCP fails:
# define static profile
#profile static_eth0
#static ip_address=192.168.1.23/24
#static routers=192.168.1.1
#static domain_name_servers=1.1.1.1

# fallback to static profile on eth0
#interface eth0
#fallback static_eth0

noipv6 
noipv4ll
```

Comment: DHCP doesn't configure 169.254.0.0 addresses - only if a a device fails to make contact with a DHCP server can it (optionally) allocate a 169.254.x.x address.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: I don't use dhcp - I just removed the daemon  "apt purge avahi-daemon". The client software has to many dependencies so I didn't remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this to the bottom of the dhcpcd.conf file and
169.254.x.x route is not added.

```
denyinterfaces veth* br*
```